# installing ubuntu-based distro in a 2tb hard drive (hardware raid)

Tags: ubuntu, raid, zentyal, fakeraid

I'm setting up a server which has got the following configuration:

1. 2tb hard drive (2 drives) raid-1 configured from bios (hardware
   raid)
2. 40gb hard drive

I would like to install the swap and the /boot on the 40gb and the / in the 2tb raid.
The alternative could be /boot, swap and / in the 40gb and /home in the 2tb raid (as this should be mainly a fileserver)+

The distribution is Zentyal 3.2

How should I partition the disks as Zentyal continues to give me error when trying to install the grub2 (in any part of the hard drive)

Thanks

Comment: That is not hardware RAID, that is fakeraid.

Comment: really? and How to setup hw raid?

Comment: First you go buy an actual RAID HBA. Then you set it up according to its directions.